# What are the XGMII control pins?

Tags: fpga, verilog, ethernet

The 10 Gigabit Media Independent Interface ([XGMII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Independent_Interface#10_Gigabit_Media_Independent_Interface)) is an interface standard that uses 72 data pins for both RX and TX. As far as I understand, of those 72 pins, only 64 are actually data, the remaining 8 being for error and flow control.

I haven't been able to find out what exactly those 8 pins are, and how they should be controlled. I'm considering writting a XGMII Verilog driver module but I cannot find the relevant specification.

What are the 8 RX and TX control pins for XGMII? Where can I find a specification? (Are there publicly available XGMII Verilog implementations?)

Comment: This document seems to glean a litttle bit of information about the control signals, although not a ton: http://www.intrinsix.com/electronic-design-solutions/intellectual-property/verification-ip/xgmii-evc

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the control bits represent how to interpret the four bytes in a given read/transmit operation.  For example, if RX_control[0] is 0, then RX_data[0:7] is normal data, but if RX_control[1] is 1, then RX_data[8:15] is special data used to indicate faults or something... that's mostly what I get from it, although the actual characters used are still the mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification for XGMII is in Clause 46 of IEEE 802.3, which starts page 187 of [this PDF](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.3-2008_section4.pdf).

Comment: The link is dead, can be found by searching `802.3-2008_section4.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the opencores 10G modules to find out on how to implement it. You could also look at the datasheet from TI on XAUI modules (www.ti.com/product/tlk3138). On Xilinx FPGA, you just connect four rocket I/Os to the XAUI modules. Also they are some pdfs floating around in the internet about the 10G standard. I believe the extra pins are used by management. Type 10G MDIO in google; there is an opencores report which describe it (http://opencores.org/websvn,filedetails?repname=ethmac10g&path=%2Fethmac10g%2Ftags%2FV10%2F10G+Ethernet+MAC+System+Design.doc). I actually help in the development of the 10G core but that was over 5 years ago.

Comment: Could you edit the links into your answer? It's more helpful when your readers don't have to find everything themselves.